# Is it possible to add a sequential number to each log event using Logback?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, elk

I have an ELK mounted and my app send logs use Logback. The problem is that I loose the events order when there are many logs with the same timestamp (many fast events in the same millisecond).

I would like to add a sequential number to keep the log events order when there is many logs at the same time. Is that possible? How?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

---

EDIT:

Sorry, I give more information about the scenario: I'm using a Springboot application which sends the logs to an ELK (Elastic-Logstash-Kibana) stack.

I need to add a field with the sequence number so then I'll be able to order the logs in Kibana using that field. Currently Kibana is ordering the logs by timestamp field but sometimes there is too many logs at the same time. The logs at the same time are unordered.

Comment: Are you having difficulty in managing logs that are the collected output of multiple requests, or the output of a single request that's mixed up?

Comment: I having difficulty to order the logs from one Springboot instance when I inspect them in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom log pattern. Please follow below link. 
https://reflectoring.io/logging-format-logback/

Comment: Sorry for missundertansding. I need to add a field with the sequence number so then I'll be able to order the logs in Kibana using that field.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<configuration>
    <sequenceNumberGenerator class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.BasicSequenceNumberGenerator"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%sequenceNumber---%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

PS:
Logback supports a sequence number field which is automatically populated at event creation. This field is fed by a sequence number generator attached to the logging context.

visit  https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html